# If $F$ has a ramification point, then is $F$ necessarily not injective?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, complex-manifolds, ramification

I thought of this question based on my other question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3813927/set-of-branch-points-isnt-discrete-but-branch-points-are-isolated).

I understand that for a nonconstant holomorphic map $F: X \to Y$ between Riemann surfaces $X$ and $Y$, both of which are connected but not necessarily compact, if $F$ is defined to have a ramification point at $p \in X$ if for all neighborhoods $U$ of $p$ in $X$, the restriction $F|_U$ is not injective.

**Question 1**: So if, on the contrary, $F$ were injective, then no $p$ is a ramification point because we could just pick $U=X$?

**Question 2**: What is the relationship between Question 1 and the fact that injective holomorphic maps between Riemann surfaces are isomorphisms onto their images ([Proposition II.3.9 in Rick Miranda - Algebraic curves and Riemann surfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBeMi.png); also see here: [Whether or not riemann surfaces can be singletons (and consequences and generalisation)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3813959/when-the-image-of-a-holomorphic-map-on-a-riemann-surface-is-also-a-riemann-surfa))?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  It looks like you’re asking about the contrapositive of a statement you know is true.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Oh right I used contrapositive. Anyway, I edited question. Thanks!

Comment: You might think about this in light of the complex analysis exercise that locally a non-constant holomorphic map $\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ looks like $f(z)=z^k$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$, and a ramification point corresponds precisely to the origin with $k\ge 2$.